# Dynamic Forms In Java PDF

Tags: java, forms, pdf, dynamic, birt

I have a requirement to fill out forms such as government forms with tight spaces for fields as you know. I have been trying to use Birt to create these and it is a huge hassle because Birt is based on grids and I am having to make 50x50 grids to try and place fields where should be ect. This is not something I would like to continue. I have also looked into PDF Forms and filling them with things like PDFBox but my forms require dynamic images and dynamic tables and it seems this is not possible with PDF Forms. I am really in a rush to get this done but cannot find anything that can fill my needs. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the forms you have to fill out? Are they fillable PDF forms? Are they XFA forms (created using LiveCycle Designer, with the ability of dynamic forms? Or are they just "plain paper" PDFs, and you try to put an overlay over them?

Comment: Right now they are just plain PDFs. I have considered making them fillable but due to my requirements for tables and images that doesn't seem to be an option. So yes I believe an overlay is my best option, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: With an overlay, you are limited to the base as much as if you would make them fillable (using Acrobat). Tables are possible (and made up quite quickly), as well as Button fields for importing images. Under these circumstances, IMHO, making fillable using Acrobat is more efficient, and therefore costs less.